# printing c++ classes in gdb without python

Tags: c++, gdb

I found out, that gdb supports python scripting, and that this is the recommended way of printing c++ classes. But I do not speak python, nor am I interested in this language. I looked up the examles to do pretty printing in python and they scared me away. I just want to make some simple classes more beautiful when debugging. To name them glm::vec2 glm::vec3 glm::mat2 etc.

Comment: [lpthw](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

Comment: If you're scared by the samples, why not just learn some Python so that next time you won't be scared away no more. Learning an extra language (or at least the basics from it) might be a better way to spend your time than to learn some (possibly obscure) feature of gdb: a language like Python might benefit you in the future, not so much as knowing how to print simple classes in gdb.

Comment: I actually expected someone would answer exactly this. My list of languages that I already know is long, including haskell prolog scala c++ go ... I can generally understand python, but I don't want to learn it. Please respect that.

Answer (score 1):

> I can generally understand python, but I don't want to learn it.

You don't need to *learn* Python, you just need to understand enough of it to cut/paste and modify the sample pretty printer.

Start from something simple, like `std::string` [pretty printer](http://tromey.com/blog/?p=524), and you'll be fine. If you can't be bothered to learn that much... you can always live with the default GDB printing :-)

Alternatively, you can also use [Guile](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Guile.html).

Comment: the question is more, is there an option, to write the printing function in C++ with a C interface that that is given by gdb, so that all gdb needs to know is that function call. The problem is not just python, it's also the weired api of gdb and the fact that for me it doesn't make sense to write the printing function of a c++ object in anything else than C++.